# dojo store isDirty

Tags: dojo

The older dojo.data API had an isDirty function to query if a store, or a selected item, had unsaved changes. I used this in the ItemFileWriteStore.

The new (since 1.7) dojo/store API doesn't seem to have this.  I'm looking at the Memory and JsonREST stores.

Is there an easy way to add this functionality, or is it a write/mixin your own ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to have these functions in the new API. The `dojo/store` is more abstract than the `dojo/data` API, because there's no API for asynchronous saving/dirty checks.

The `dojo/data` write API was meant to be used in combination with a service that should be updated when calling `save()`. Because there could be a difference between the local and remote version, they had to add a function like `isDirty()` to verify that.

The new `dojo/store` API has no API for asynchronous saving. The stores you mention are not using asynchronous saving either, so they don't have such a feature.

1. **dojo/store/Memory** is an in memory storage, there is no service behind this store, so saving it to a service is something you will have to implement here, there's no need to have a `save()` or `isDirty()` feature.
2. **dojo/store/JsonRest** immediately pushes local changes to the RESTful webservice behind this store. This means there are no dirty objects that aren't saved yet. Because of this, there's no need to have a `save()` or `isDirty()` feature here either.

---

If you really need an asynchronous save, you will have to create your own store, which you can extend with your own `save()` and `isDirty()` API.

I think the old API was to specified (the API was only valid for certain stores), that's why I think they left it out. But there's nobody that's stopping you from creating your own additional API.